# Selected option with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am making a html page to edit an item in angular.  All the text inputs populate with the object in the `$scope`. The `select` list is populating but isn't selecting the option in the `$scope` object.  This is the markup

```
<select data-ng-model="myItem.Category" 
    data-ng-options="c.Name for c in Categories" 
    data-ng-values="c.CategoryId for c in Categories" 
    data-ng-selected="myItem.Category" ></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each category has an id (or somme other unique field) use this:

```
<select data-ng-model="myItem.Category" 
        data-ng-options="c.CategoryId for c in Categories track by c.id"></select>
```

This will allow the matching of your model and option to be based upon `id`

The ng-model will define your selected value, and ng-options defines the items to show in the select.